# Hanging heavy object in bedroom

Tags: drywall, mirror

I need to hang a mirror in my bedroom.  I purchased some anchors assuming the drywall would be 3/8ths of an inch thick.  However, when I drill my pilot holes, I realize the drywall in my bedroom is definitely more than an inch thick!  I live in a residential condominium tower (35 stories high) and the wall I am drilling into is one that I share with my neighbour.  At this point I don't know how thick the drywall is, but I know I'm not drilling into a stud.

So assuming this drywall thickness is normal, should I continue to use the anchors that I bought?  See picture below.  These anchors require a hole that is 1/4 inch wide but since I'm not confident in using these anymore I've stopped drilling.  What should I do?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBC6i.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

My opinion of the anchors that you posted is pretty low. There are far better anchors available than those. As a matter of fact those anchors are touted to be for "solid material walls, floors and ceilings". I personally do not consider drywall to be a particularly solid material in the same way that wood, brick or concrete would be.

Your wall is probably made up two layers of 1/2" drywall to be both a fire stop and sound deadening between the neighbors unit and yours.

If I were to be hanging a heavy mirror on 1" thickness surface drywall I would look at [toggle type anchors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-0-25-in-x-2-5-in-Yellow-Zinc-Toggle-Bolts/3183831?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-ToolsAndHardware-_-HollowWallAnchors-_-3183831:TOGGLER&CAWELAID=&kpid=3183831&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=1108&k_clickID=191b5cb0-3cd6-7f49-8afa-0000465d92bd) that look like this:

[image]

Comment: +1 I share your disdain of such anchors. And they are definitely not intended for drywall. They grip by pressure against a *solid surface* and even lack ribs common on plastic drywall anchors.